# Creating a radial-gradient effect around the Mouse

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make it so that whereever the mouse moves to, there is a radial-gradient background around the mouse. Right now, it doesn't exactly work the way I want it to. Theres sometimes a delay when I move the mouse and the background doesnt follow.

Below is my background component code. I'm using the mousemove event listener, but I'm guessing it fires too fast, causing the delay.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Background = ({ children }) => {
    const [mouseStyle, setMouseStyle] = useState(null);

    // Event handler for mouse movement
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        // Get mouse coordinates and element dimensions
        const { clientX, clientY } = event;
        const { left, top, width, height } = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Calculate spotlight position as a percentage of element dimensions
        const spotlightX = ((clientX - left) / width) * 100;
        const spotlightY = ((clientY - top) / height) * 100;

        // Generate the radial gradient color based on spotlight
        const gradientColor = `radial-gradient(500px circle at ${spotlightX}% ${spotlightY}%, rgba(29, 78, 216, 0.15), transparent 80%)`;

        // Update the spotlight style state with the gradient color
        setMouseStyle({ background: gradientColor });
    };

    // Setting the styling of the components
    const container = `
        bg-slate-900
        leading-relaxed
        text-slate-400
        antialiased
        selection:bg-teal-300
        selection:text-teal-900
    `;
    const mouse = `
        pointer-events-none 
        fixed 
        inset-0 
        z-30 
        transition 
        duration-300 
        lg:absolute
    `
    const position = `
        mx-auto 
        min-h-screen 
        max-w-screen-xl 
        px-6 py-12 
        font-sans 
        md:px-12 
        md:py-20 
        lg:px-24 
        lg:py-0
    `
    
    // Return component
    return (
        <div
            className={container}
            style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        >
            <div className='relative'>
                <div
                    className={mouse}
                    style={mouseStyle}
                />
                <div className={position}>
                    { children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```